# solving if preg_match_all no output

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-match-all

I'm currently working on a script. The following code is included:

`if(preg_match_all('!href="(\[^"\]+fref=fr_tab)"!',$contents,$aMatch))`

This only applies if part of the link `fref=fr-tab` + an `&` or `?` stands, right?

When I check the link, it contains `fref=fr-tab` but no `&` or `?` but a semicolon. I tried a lot to get the script to work. Unfortunately, I haven't succeeded so far.

How can I change the line?

Try to print the array with part of this code:

```
$contents = $Curl->fetch_url($link);

if(preg_match_all('!href="([^"]+fref=fr_tab)"!',$contents,$aMatch))
{   
    print_r($aMatch);
    exit;
}
else
```

Comment: Can you add a couple of link examples to the question, along with the array output that is desired?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern matches `fref=fr_tab` directly followed by `"` so if the url is longer it will not match.

You could for example match optional characters other than `"` after the match, and use word boundaries to prevent a partial word match.

```
\bhref="([^"]+\bfref=fr_tab\b[^"]*)"
```

See the matches at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CwfWsW/1).

You could make the pattern more specific also matching `;` but if you go that route I would recommend using [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead with `PHP_URL_QUERY`

```
\bhref="([^"]*[?&;]fref=fr_tab(?:[&;][^"]*)?)"
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aFAS9r/1).

**Note** that in the question you also refer to `fref=fr-tab` with a hyphen, but the pattern has an underscore.